# How to mock readline.on('SIGINT')?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I have this piece of code:

```
function getMsg() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var input = [];
    var rl = readline.createInterface({
      input: process.stdin,
      output: process.stdout
    });
    rl.on('line', function (cmd) {
      if (cmd.trim()) {
        input.push(cmd);
      } else {
        rl.close();
      }
    });
    rl.on('close', function () {
      rl.close();
      resolve(input.join('\n'));
    });
    rl.on('SIGINT', reject);
  });
}
```

I'm trying to test this function, my attempt, so far, is this:

```
it('should reject if SIGINT is sent', function () {
  sandbox.stub(readline, 'createInterface', function () {
    return {
      on: function (action, callback) {
        callback();
      },
      prompt: function () {},
      close: function () {}
    };
  });

  return getMsg().then(null).catch(function () {
    expect(true).to.be.equal(true);
  });
});
```

But of course, that doesn't simulate a `SIGINT`, how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need a different setup:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter
...
it('should reject if SIGINT is sent', function () {
  let emitter = new EventEmitter();
  sandbox.stub(readline, 'createInterface', function () {
    emitter.close = () => {};
    return emitter;
  });

  let promise = getMsg().then(function() {
    throw Error('should not have resolved');
  }, function (err) {
    expect(true).to.be.equal(true);
  });

  emitter.emit('SIGINT');

  return promise;
});
```

The object returned by `readline.createInterface()` inherits from [`EventEmitter`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter), so that's what the stub will return. The additional `close` function is simply added to it to prevent errors when it gets called.

You can't return the promise returned by `getMsg` directly, because that doesn't give you a chance to emit the `SIGINT` "signal" (really just an event, but for testing purposes it'll work just fine). So the promise is stored.

The test should fail with the "fulfilled" handler gets called, which had to be done explicitly, otherwise Mocha thinks the test passed.

Next, the `SIGINT` is sent (which should trigger the rejection handler as intended), and the promise is returned.

Comment: I understand the reject vs catch. No need to expand on that.

Comment: Thanks for the emitter, I didn't know that existed. I'll try it out.

Comment: @RafaelBarros I removed it to lessen the noise :)

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks for bringing the `Emitter` to my knowledge. Final point: you missed a semi-colon.

Comment: where you getting sandbox.stub, can you show what that is

Comment: @PositiveGuy it's a feature of `sinon`: http://sinonjs.org/releases/v6.1.0/sandbox/